Data.table version of rowwise prop.test
This is the same question as Apply prop.test to each row in a dataframe, but I am seeking a data.table answer that doesn't rely on another package like broom::tidy. Short question: How to run prop.test on all the rows in a data.table and assign the results to columns.
# test data
dt1 <- structure(list(Strategy = c("active immunization", "cell regeneration/restoration",
"cellular senescence", "combination", "energy metabolism", "epigenome/transcription",
"general neuroprotection", "immune response", "lipid metabolism",
"metal ion modulation", "microtubule stabilization", "neuromodulator/transmission",
"neurotrophin pathway", "non-pharmacological", "oxidative stress",
"passive immunization", "proteostasis network", "tau aggregation",
"tau enzyme/PTM", "tau isoform imbalance correction", "tau propagation",
"tau reduction"), Outcome = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE",
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE",
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE"), X = c(14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L,
25L, 32L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 4L, 18L, 9L, 46L, 33L, 26L, 43L, 2L,
1L, 6L), N = c(18L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 25L, 39L, 8L, 3L, 7L,
19L, 5L, 22L, 10L, 63L, 38L, 27L, 48L, 3L, 2L, 6L)), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), sorted = c("Strategy",
"Outcome"))

So I can usually flatten a test object or formula with unlist and slice as desired but the prop.test object isn't working as expected. This can be fixed by changing it to a tibble with broom::tidy, although I imagine slower and requires a dependency:
test <- prop.test(dt1[[1,3]], dt1[[1,4]])
unlist(test)[c(1, 3, 6:7)]
 statistic.X-squared              p.value            conf.int1            conf.int2
               "4.5" "0.0338948535246893"  "0.519186146108054"  "0.926276897802783"


# does not work
dt1[, c("chi", "p", "lower", "upper") := unlist(prop.test(x = X, n = N))[c(1, 3, 6:7)], by = .I]
# does work, but...
dt1[, c("chi", "p", "lower", "upper") := broom::tidy(prop.test(x = X, n = N))[c(2:3, 5:6)], by = .I]

> dt1
Key: <Strategy, Outcome>
                            Strategy Outcome     X     N       chi            p      lower     upper
                              <char>  <char> <int> <int>     <num>        <num>      <num>     <num>
 1:              active immunization      DE    14    18  4.500000 3.389485e-02 0.51918615 0.9262769
 2:    cell regeneration/restoration      DE     1     4  0.250000 6.170751e-01 0.01319116 0.7805735
 3:              cellular senescence      DE     1     1  0.000000 1.000000e+00 0.05462076 1.0000000
 4:                      combination      DE     1     2  0.000000 1.000000e+00 0.09453121 0.9054688
 5:                energy metabolism      DE     7     7  5.142857 2.334220e-02 0.56093387 1.0000000
 6:          epigenome/transcription      DE     2     2  0.500000 4.795001e-01 0.19786746 1.0000000
 7:          general neuroprotection      DE    25    25 23.040000 1.586656e-06 0.83422699 1.0000000
 8:                  immune response      DE    32    39 14.769231 1.215020e-04 0.65890539 0.9189739
 9:                 lipid metabolism      DE     5     8  0.125000 7.236736e-01 0.25894769 0.8975920
10:             metal ion modulation      DE     1     3  0.000000 1.000000e+00 0.01765279 0.8746655
11:        microtubule stabilization      DE     6     7  2.285714 1.305700e-01 0.42007834 0.9924972
12:      neuromodulator/transmission      DE    15    19  5.263158 2.178146e-02 0.53902028 0.9302931
13:             neurotrophin pathway      DE     4     5  0.800000 3.710934e-01 0.29879105 0.9894700
14:              non-pharmacological      DE    18    22  7.681818 5.577994e-03 0.58992882 0.9400827
15:                 oxidative stress      DE     9    10  4.900000 2.685670e-02 0.54115398 0.9947577
16:             passive immunization      DE    46    63 12.444444 4.192370e-04 0.60131748 0.8306991
17:             proteostasis network      DE    33    38 19.184211 1.186911e-05 0.71116190 0.9505271
18:                  tau aggregation      DE    26    27 21.333333 3.859616e-06 0.79110819 0.9980636
19:                   tau enzyme/PTM      DE    43    48 28.520833 9.269570e-08 0.76556981 0.9610103
20: tau isoform imbalance correction      DE     2     3  0.000000 1.000000e+00 0.12533447 0.9823472
21:                  tau propagation      DE     1     2  0.000000 1.000000e+00 0.09453121 0.9054688
22:                    tau reduction      DE     6     6  4.166667 4.122683e-02 0.51681705 1.0000000
                            Strategy Outcome     X     N       chi            p      lower     upper


I'd extract the prop.test result first, then create another list to assign the output:
dt1[
   ,
    c("chi","p","lower","upper") := {
       p <- prop.test(X, N)[c("statistic","p.value","conf.int")]
       .(p$statistic, p$p.value, p$conf.int[1], p$conf.int[2])
    },
    by=.I
]

##Key: <Strategy, Outcome>
##                            Strategy Outcome     X     N       chi            p      lower     upper
##                              <char>  <char> <int> <int>     <num>        <num>      <num>     <num>
## 1:              active immunization      DE    14    18  4.500000 3.389485e-02 0.51918615 0.9262769
## 2:    cell regeneration/restoration      DE     1     4  0.250000 6.170751e-01 0.01319116 0.7805735
## ...


Using lapply to iterate over the unlist results
library(data.table)

dt1[, c("chi", "p", "lower", "upper") := lapply(unlist(prop.test(X, N))[
    c("statistic.X-squared", "p.value", "conf.int1", "conf.int2")], \(x) 
      as.numeric(x)), by = .I]
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> dt1
Key: <Strategy, Outcome>
                            Strategy Outcome     X     N       chi            p
                              <char>  <char> <int> <int>     <num>        <num>
 1:              active immunization      DE    14    18  4.500000 3.389485e-02
 2:    cell regeneration/restoration      DE     1     4  0.250000 6.170751e-01
 3:              cellular senescence      DE     1     1  0.000000 1.000000e+00
 4:                      combination      DE     1     2  0.000000 1.000000e+00
 5:                energy metabolism      DE     7     7  5.142857 2.334220e-02
 6:          epigenome/transcription      DE     2     2  0.500000 4.795001e-01
 7:          general neuroprotection      DE    25    25 23.040000 1.586656e-06
 8:                  immune response      DE    32    39 14.769231 1.215020e-04
 9:                 lipid metabolism      DE     5     8  0.125000 7.236736e-01
10:             metal ion modulation      DE     1     3  0.000000 1.000000e+00
11:        microtubule stabilization      DE     6     7  2.285714 1.305700e-01
12:      neuromodulator/transmission      DE    15    19  5.263158 2.178146e-02
13:             neurotrophin pathway      DE     4     5  0.800000 3.710934e-01
14:              non-pharmacological      DE    18    22  7.681818 5.577994e-03
15:                 oxidative stress      DE     9    10  4.900000 2.685670e-02
16:             passive immunization      DE    46    63 12.444444 4.192370e-04
17:             proteostasis network      DE    33    38 19.184211 1.186911e-05
18:                  tau aggregation      DE    26    27 21.333333 3.859616e-06
19:                   tau enzyme/PTM      DE    43    48 28.520833 9.269570e-08
20: tau isoform imbalance correction      DE     2     3  0.000000 1.000000e+00
21:                  tau propagation      DE     1     2  0.000000 1.000000e+00
22:                    tau reduction      DE     6     6  4.166667 4.122683e-02
                            Strategy Outcome     X     N       chi            p
         lower     upper
         <num>     <num>
 1: 0.51918615 0.9262769
 2: 0.01319116 0.7805735
 3: 0.05462076 1.0000000
 4: 0.09453121 0.9054688
 5: 0.56093387 1.0000000
 6: 0.19786746 1.0000000
 7: 0.83422699 1.0000000
 8: 0.65890539 0.9189739
 9: 0.25894769 0.8975920
10: 0.01765279 0.8746655
11: 0.42007834 0.9924972
12: 0.53902028 0.9302931
13: 0.29879105 0.9894700
14: 0.58992882 0.9400827
15: 0.54115398 0.9947577
16: 0.60131748 0.8306991
17: 0.71116190 0.9505271
18: 0.79110819 0.9980636
19: 0.76556981 0.9610103
20: 0.12533447 0.9823472
21: 0.09453121 0.9054688
22: 0.51681705 1.0000000
         lower     upper


Define a function prop.test.dt which is like prop.test except it returns a data.table.
We have added an optional argument nowarn which by default is FALSE but if set to TRUE will suppress the prop.test warnings but no others. Finally use it with by= and extract any columns wanted.
The prop.test.dt function returns all the informration output by prop.test so that it can be reused for similar applications in the future which may want all of them or a different subset.
library (data.table)

prop.test.dt <- function(..., nowarn = FALSE) {
  f <- if (nowarn) suppressWarnings else identity
  prop.test(...) |>
    f() |>
    unclass() |>
    as.data.table() |>
    transform(lwr = conf.int[[1]], upr = conf.int[[2]], 
      conf.level = attr(conf.int, "conf.level"), conf.int = NULL) |>
    _[1, ]
}

dt1[, prop.test.dt(X, N), by = .(Strategy, Outcome, X, N)][,
     .(Outcome, X, N, chi = statistic, p.value, lwr, upr)]

